# File not found when opening a file whose name I get from os.listdir

Tags: python

I'm trying to read the first 20 characters of several files that I have in a folder using the code shown below:

```
import os
path = raw_input("Enter the path: ")
listing = sorted(os.listdir(path))
for infile in listing:
    print "current file is: " + infile
    with open(infile) as fl: # Use fl to refer to the file object
        #print infile
        data = fl.read(20)
        print data
        fl.close()
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Enter the path: /home/david/dat_files_new

current file is: raw_57_0000.dat
# == pyFAI calibrati
current file is: raw_57_0001.dat

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-53-7292764186b6> in <module>()
      7 for infile in listing:
      8     print "current file is: " + infile
----> 9     with open(infile) as fl: # Use fl to refer to the file object
     10         #print infile
     11         data = fl.read(20)

IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'raw_CL20_57_0001.dat'
```

I can list all the files in the directory if I comment the with statement and everything that it is below.

This is what the code does:

- Sort the files within a directory --> done
- Print name of first file --> done
- Read the first 20 characters of the first file --> done
- Print name of seconde file --> done
- Read the first 20 characters of the second file --> failed
- Read the first 20 characters of the second file

Comment: You're telling them to enter the path and then trying to open the file wherever they happen to run the script. Two choices: pass the entered path to `open` along with an `os.path.join`, or `os.chdir` them to where they need to be.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that is actually pretty bad dupe.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I wasn't perfectly happy with it either. Just looking for something with a few `os.path.join` examples of different varieties in the answer.

Comment: That one that I found is a bit better for you @david_doji because the accepted answer answers your next question as well ;)